# What strategies do you use for fetching and caching paginated collections, specifically in angular or restangular?

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, caching, restangular

Let's say an app consumes data from a REST api that exposes paginated collections, and the number of items in a collection can be infinitely large (i.e. too many items to fetch all at once and store in a browser session).

What are good strategies for fetching, caching and invalidating the cache of such data?

Say, the API is like,

```
GET /users?page=1&per_page=50
```

With a response like below (i.e. includes the collection data + paging meta data)

```
{
  "paging": {
    "per_page": 20,
    "page": 1,
    "previous": null,
    "self": "/api/v1/users?per_page=20&page=1",
    "next": "/api/v1/users?per_page=20&page=2"
  },
  "data": [
    // first 20 users
  ]
}
```

The client may or may not load the collection in contiguous pages, one page at a time. The users in the collection may be changed, by any client. Eventual consistency is sufficient and I'm not concerned about write conflicts at this time.

The question is in the context of an angularjs app, but is a generic scenario.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do/did is use angular's [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) and have one entry for each API endpoint. So if your current URL is `/api/v1/users?per_page=20&page=1` the cache's key would be `/api/v1/users` without any pagination parameters. Then once the response is returned do the following in the function which handles the data:

```
// add customer insert method somewhere
Array.prototype.insert = function (index, item) {
  this.splice(index, 0, item);
};

var cachedData = $cacheFactory.get(key);

var insertPosition = pageSize * currentPage;

cachedData.insert(insertPosition, returnedData);

$cacheFactory.put(cachedData);
```

Probably a lot simpler than it would have to be in a real life scenario, but you get the idea.

Comment: Hi @just-nik, what do you do when fetching a single item from a cached collection? Traverse the local data and look for it first? And what do you do when any item in the collection gets updated and (and saved back to the server)?

Comment: Yes, probably.
I would just initialize the array with the number of all items. Then you can update a single item at any time